# Display COUNT of how many rows in DB table in a DataGrid Column WPF C#

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I have been spinning my wheels trying to display how many rows there are in my DB into a DataGrid Column called '**JobsCount**' using COUNT.

```
sqlCon.Open();
            string query = "SELECT UserName, COUNT(UserName) as count FROM tblJobs WHERE JobStatus != 'Booked' Group by UserName";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);

            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                adapter.Fill(dt);
                tblJobsBooked.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            }
            sqlCon.Close();
```

**DataGrid Columns**

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="User" Binding="{Binding UserName}"/>
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Jobs Booked" Binding="{Binding JobsCount}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

The COUNT should be calculated by UserName.

Comment: The databinding in your DataGridTextColumn binds to JobsCount whereas the column in the SQL statement is count

Comment: Face palm, completely overlooked it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
string query = "SELECT UserName, COUNT(UserName) as count FROM tblJobs WHERE JobStatus != 'Booked' Group by UserName";
```

To this:

```
string query = "SELECT UserName, COUNT(UserName) as JobsCount FROM tblJobs WHERE JobStatus != 'Booked' Group by UserName";
```

See the difference? The DataGrid can't bind unless the names match exactly.